# How to reduce the size of a side by side video comparison without definition loss

Tags: video, video-processing, avisynth

I have combined two different protein simulation videos (each 700 KB) to a single video for side by side comparision horizontally, but the single file size has increased to 130 MB.

I have used Virtualdub and Avisynth for this purpose. 
 
 I have used AVI format and i need to save the single file in the same format. 
 Avisynth code (.avs) as follows:

> version()
>
> ReduceBy2
>
> a = AVISource("C:\Users\suresh\Desktop\VirtualDub-1\a1.avi")
>
> b = AVISource("C:\Users\suresh\Desktop\VirtualDub-1\a2.avi")
>
> StackHorizontal(a,b)

Can any one point me how to reduce the file size without losing the resolution of the video?.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: That's not a programming question. The encoding parameters are set in the application you use (VirtualDub) in its menus. Voting to move to superuser.com

Comment: Superuser isn't really friendly for newcomers, people aren't allowed to answer questions linking to wiki and whatnot.

Comment: @ wOxxOm thank you. that works. The video size reduced to less than 10 MB by using compressed video option in VirtualDub.